# Appcelerator: [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I know this question has been asked lots of times, but answers given did not solve my problem so far.

When trying to build an app to either a Android-device/-simulator/-package, Appcelerator comes with this error:

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1

- I checked weither all Android-sdk's where installed correctly.
- In the terminal I did: **`appc logout -D` / `appc login`**
- I cleaned the project, including deleting Build- and Resources-folder by hand
- Ran: **`appc setup`**
- Some other terminal-lines I stumbled upon: **`npm install alloy -g`** and **`npm install appc-cli-titanium`**
- Installed Appcelerator-updates
- Added  **`<tool-api-level>17< /tool-api-level>`**  to tiapp.xml
- This line is in the Android-manifest: **`<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="26" android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>`**

With the console in trace-mode, this is what I get:

```
[INFO] :   ----- MVC GENERATION -----
[INFO] :   [app.tss] global style processing...
[INFO] :   [global style] writing to cache...
[INFO] :   [index.xml] view processing...
[INFO] :   style:      "index.tss"
[INFO] :   view:       "index.xml"
[INFO] :   controller: "index.js"
[INFO] :   created:    "Resources/android/alloy/controllers/index.js"
[DEBUG] :  map:                "build/map/Resources/android/alloy/controllers/index.js.map"
[INFO] :   created:     "Resources/android/alloy/styles/index.js"
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   [app.js] Titanium entry point processing...
[DEBUG] :  /Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
[DEBUG] :        throw err;
[DEBUG] :        ^
[DEBUG] :  TypeError: unknown: Property property of MemberExpression expected node to be of a type ["Identifier"] but instead got "BooleanLiteral"
[DEBUG] :      at validate     (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/index.js:109:13)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.validate (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-types/lib/definitions/core.js:412:50)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.validate (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-types/lib/index.js:505:9)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath._replaceWith (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:176:7)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.replaceWith (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/replacement.js:160:8)
[DEBUG] :      at PluginPass.Identifier (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/ast/optimizer-plugin.js:65:11)
[DEBUG] :      at newFn (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:21)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath._call (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.call (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:105:12)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:103:17)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:190:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
[DEBUG] :      at NodePath.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:115:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visitSingle (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:108:19)
[DEBUG] :      at TraversalContext.visit (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:192:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.traverse.node (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:114:17)
[DEBUG] :      at traverse (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/index.js:79:12)
[DEBUG] :      at File.transform (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:548:35)
[DEBUG] :      at /Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:73:19
[DEBUG] :      at File.wrap (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:564:16)
[DEBUG] :      at Pipeline.transformFromAst (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:70:17)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.exports.generateCodeAndSourceMap (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/sourceMapper.js:112:27)
[DEBUG] :      at generateAppJs (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/index.js:554:16)
[DEBUG] :      at module.exports (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/commands/compile/index.js:480:2)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/Alloy/alloy.js:112:46)
[DEBUG] :      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
[DEBUG] :      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[DEBUG] :      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[DEBUG] :      at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
[DEBUG] :      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/bas/.appcelerator/install/6.3.0/package/node_modules/alloy/bin/alloy:3:1)
[DEBUG] :      at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
[DEBUG] :      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
[DEBUG] :      at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
[DEBUG] :      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
[DEBUG] :      at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
[DEBUG] :      at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
[DEBUG] :      at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
[DEBUG] :      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
[DEBUG] :      at bootstrap_node.js:505:3
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Comment: use build tools 26, with CLI 6.3 and TiSDK 6.3. So also install those build tools properly using the android tools

Comment: In Android Studio I already installed Android 8.0 (SDK/Sources/Google APIs Intel x86 Atom Image/etc.) ... but how do I 'use' it? Do you mean I have to target it using this tag in the tiapp.xml? 
`<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="26" android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25"/>`
I use this as sdk-version: `<sdk-version>6.3.0.GA</sdk-version>`
 ... not sure how to use CLI

Comment: use 26 as target, not 25. Have you installed build tools 26? Thats different as any image/sdk

Comment: In Android Studio I checked all Android 8.0 stuff, so as a part of that, Build Tools 26 are installed as well I guess?

Comment: Your target is 25, build tools are separate tab in android studio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably solve this by reverting back to cli 6.2.2
6.3 replaces the old version of file minification to allow ES6 syntax but this is obviously causing a problem in you case.

Just execute "appc use 6.2.2" in the command line (without the quotes of course) and make sure you see Alloy 1.9.x used in the logs before the lines you pasted.

Comment: The first time after executing this command line, installing on the emulator went well. The second attempt I received this error message again, but now it just works well again, both on the emulator and on my device.  Thanks!  But out of curiosity, changing the Titanium SDK in the tiapp.xml/overview is something different than executing this command line? Build properties is still saying 6.3.0.GA

Comment: Correct. Here you are not changing the SDK but the build process which chooses the functions that minify your code after is it generated.