# Appcelerator Titanium (ERROR - Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1)

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

### **System Configuration Detail-**

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.13.1
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 8589934592
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 8.0.0
  npm Version                 = 5.0.0
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.14
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 6.3.0.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/imac4/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/6.3.0.GA
  Target Platform             = android
```

When I am running my code on Android Device then ERROR shows. I applied "HINI" and "RENE POT" suggestion in earlier post but it didn't work. Can anyone please tell me "System Configuration Detail" is right?

Earlier post which didn't work-

[Appcelerator: [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47159506/appcelerator-error-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination-proces)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Appcelerator SDK 6.2.2.GA and 6.3.0.GA are causing all kinds of issues, and one of them is the same error you describe. It also depends on your emulator settings (if you it of course).

SDK 6.1.2.GA and 7.0.1.GA do not cause this error, running the same code (I only change SDK version in Tiapp.xml)

Node.JS version is 8.9.3 and npm version is 5.5.1 in my case

Comment: Hi Sake! I found the solution before 2 days ago. I was using latest appcelerator titanium studio (5.0.0). I think It has some new rules to configure Android SDK and it has bugs. So I switched to older version of Titanium studio (4.8.1) and its working fine on Titanium SDK (6.3.0) and (7.0.2).